# printing of a Data struct values in hex

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct AbcStruct{

   short        LD;
   short        EL;
   short        CL;        
   AbcStruct( short b, short res = 0, short lr = 1000): LD( b ), EL(res), CL( lr ) { }
};

int main () 
{

    struct AbcStruct A2(200, 100, 100);

    char *string_ptr = (char *)&A2;
    kk = sizeof(AbcStruct);

    while(kk--)
        printf(" %x ", *string_ptr++);
}
```

Output (AbcStruct in Hex):

```
ffffffc8  0  64  0  64  0
```

I'm wondering why the output of first element contains 4 bytes: `ffffffc8` when I was expecting it wouldd just print `c8`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does this because the first bit of the char you're printing is `1`, thus the char is interpreted as a negative number. When you're printing using the default `%x` format, the value to be printed is interpreted as being an `int` (much larger than the `char`). Thus, the sign [gets copied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to all other positions, making you see those `f`s in the output.

One fix would be to print using `%hhx` (you're telling `printf` that you're printing `unsigned char` values).

```
printf(" %hhx ", *string_ptr++);
```

Another fix will be to change the type of the `string_ptr` to be `unsigned char`

```
unsigned char *string_ptr = (char *)&A2;
```

Or, you can combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling `printf()` to treat what is returned from the address pointed to by `string_ptr` as an `unsigned int` (which I guess is 32-bits long on your system) rather than an `unsigned char`.

Try this:

```
unsigned char *string_ptr = (unsigned char *)&A2;
kk = sizeof(AbcStruct);
while(kk--)
{
    unsigned char c = *string_ptr++;
    printf(" %x ", (unsigned)c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the width option in printf format specifier to print as many characters of the address as you would prefer. For instance, here you could use %2X as your format specifier.

Comment: This will only hide the problem :)